# Unable to check/uncheck a checkbox

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to check different checkbox available but I am not able to get the id for the same.I tried xpath :

@browser.checkbox(:xpath => "//SPAN[@id='incentive_4000215652']").set
and
 @browser.checkbox.span(:id => 'incentive_4000215652').set

The link to page is
https://secure.bestprice.rankingsandreviews.com/nc/configurator/301937

Click on Edit besides Exterior color and click Incentives tab.

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: `set` method is not available for span(), you can't call span().set, set is available for checkbox.

Comment: untag `ruby-on-rails`, that's no way related to your question.

Comment: Untagged. I want to check a checkbox which is span. Any suggestions? @RAJ

Comment: You would to click that checkbox,right? You want to locate and click that checkbox, that's your requirement,right?

Comment: Yes thats right

Comment: So I use this `2017 GM Conquest Cash` string to locate that corresponding check box, that would be more meaning,right?

Comment: Yes thats right I tried that using label but did not work

Comment: I update an answer below, try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
browser.element(text: "2017 GM Conquest Cash").parent.preceding_sibling.span.click
```

Or use this

```
browser.element(xpath: "//*[normalize-space()='2017 GM Conquest Cash']/../preceding-sibling::td/span").click
```

If you change the text inside, then it click the corresponding checkbox.

Second one is bit faster than the first one, because WATIR doesn't go to form the xpath since xpath is directly available to you.

Full code follows here

```
browser.goto('https://secure.bestprice.rankingsandreviews.com/nc/configurator/307715')

browser.element(:id => 's2id_select_style').click

browser.element(xpath: ".//*[@id='select2-drop']/div/input").send_keys('Convertible LT 1LT', :tab)

browser.element(id: 'edit_color').click

browser.span(text: 'Incentives').click

browser.element(text: "2017 GM Conquest Cash").parent.preceding_sibling.span.click
```

Or

```
browser.element(xpath: "//*[normalize-space()='2017 GM Conquest Cash']/../preceding-sibling::td/span").click
```

Comment: Thanks @RAJ again.Do you use any tool for finding xpath?

Comment: The kind of above xpath can't be produced by any tool, You need to learn to write. But there is a mozilla firepath which helps you to take the xpath of the particular xpath. I would suggest you to use firefox than chrome! And also You don't have to write xpath as long as you are using WATIR, it's necessary if you use selenium Ruby binding. Look at my first solution where I haven't write any xpath, WATIR writes at the back end.